# What's wrong with the following proof that any interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

Suppose not. Let $U, V$ be nonempty disjoint open sets such that $(a,b) = U \cup V$. Let $x \in U, y \in V$, and w.l.o.g. assume that $x < y$. Consider the set $S = \{z \in V | z > x\} \subseteq V$. Since $S$ is nonempty (because $y \in S$), and $x$ is a lower bound, so infimum of the set $S$ exists; call it $\alpha$. Note further that $\alpha \in (a,b)$ because $x \leq \alpha \leq y$.

Now, if $\alpha \in U$, then since $U$ is open, there is ball of some radius (say, $\epsilon$) centered at $\alpha$ in $U$, which is also contained in $(a,b)$. But that contradicts $\alpha$ being the inf, because $\alpha+\epsilon/2$ is a lower bound for $S$, and it is strictly greater than $\alpha$.

Similarly, if $\alpha \in V$, we again have a similar situation, and we can find an element in $S$ which is smaller than $\alpha$. A contradiction.

Thus we get a contradiction either way.  So such a decomposition into sets is not possible. This concludes the argument.

It deviates from the standard proof, but only a little. It was graded as incorrect. So I am wondering what is wrong with this argument?

Comment: You said "Since ..., so ..." which sounds very strange. Why the "so"? "Since I like red fruit, so I like apples" sounds so weird.

Comment: Ask the grader why it was graded as incorrect. That is your right.

Comment: The second paragrpah doesn't make sense to me. Explain how you get a  contradiction to the  fact that $\alpha$ is the infimum of $S$.

Comment: Because if $\epsilon$ is the radius of the ball, then $\alpha + \epsilon/2$ is also a lower bound for $S$, and it is greater than $\alpha$. That is a contradiction to the assumption that $\alpha$ is the inf.

Comment: @student except for the "so", I think your solution (even before the edits) is correct and well written.

Comment: The only information I have about $r=\alpha+\epsilon/2$ is that $r\in U$. How do you guarantee that $r<s$, for every $s\in S$?

Comment: Because $s \in V, \alpha \leq s$. In other words, if $ \alpha \leq s \leq \alpha + \epsilon/2$, then $s$ is in the $\epsilon$ ball, and therefore in $U$. But our set $S$ is contained in $V$.

Comment: @mathworker21: Thanks! Since I got full points after regrading, so I am going to leave it as it is.

Comment: @student lol nice one. I'm surprised it doesn't sound weird to you.

Comment: @mathworker21: It is weird. But It escaped me in the beginning, and then I am just letting it be. :-)  In my defense though, I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a correct argument as confirmed via regrading. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1172043)

Comment: @YaniorWeg he/she put more than "thank you"

Comment: @mathworker21, Sorry. Did not notice that this was a proof-verification question.